# Combination of button clicks

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, order-theory

The question is stated below:

**Imagine a machine with two buttons: A and B. For any integer N, you have to perform N clicks on button A and N clicks on button B. It implies that the total number of clicks is 2N. At any time, the number of clicks on button B must not exceed that on button A.**

**(a). For any number of N, how many orders of button clicks are there?**

My understandings:

I represent the orders as sets containing different orders of A and B.

Let *a* and *b* be the number of clicks on A and B respectively at a certain moment.

For example, when N=2, {A,A,B,B} is valid, while {B,B,A,A} is invalid.

In {B,B,A,A}, when B is first clicked, a is 0 and b is 1, thus it is invalid.

I have found out that:

When N=2, the number of orders = 2:

{A,A,B,B}, {A,B,A,B}

When N=3, the number of orders = 5.

{A,A,A,B,B,B}, {A,A,B,A,B,B}, {A,B,A,B,A,B}, {A,B,A,A,B,B}, {A,A,B,B,A,B}

Does anyone have an idea? Thank you.

Comment: Think about this : "A=(" [ opening a bracket ] & "B=)" [ closing a bracket ] & then we can see that in Mathematical Calculations , we can use some close bracket only when there is some open bracket. This is a Solved Problem !

Comment: This is a [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) problem.

Comment: @paw88789 Sorry it's a typo. There should be only 5 orderings in this case